# Saving a mongo document with mongoose returns the updated document, but didn't save in the database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

My issue today is with MongoDB and mongoose in javascript. So first off I have this schema:

```js
var playerModel = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Users",
  },
  class: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  level: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1,
  },
  spells: {
    type: [String],
    default: ["", "", "", "", ""],
  },
  inventory: [], <- IMPORTANT
  toolbelt: {
    axe: [{}],
    pickaxe: [{}],
    fishingrod: [{}],
    hammer: [{}],
    saw: [{}],
    sewingkit: [{}],
    knife: [{}],
    gemkit: [{}],
    food: [{}],
    potion: [{}],
  },
  gear: {
    weapon: [{}],
    head: [{}],
    chest: [{}],
    gloves: [{}],
    legs: [{}],
    shoes: [{}],
    earrings: [{}],
    ring: [{}],
    necklace: [{}],
  },
  gold: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  bagSize: {
    type: Number,
    default: 20,
  },
  skills: {
    type: [userSkills],
    default: defaultSkills,
  },
});
```

and my problem is with `inventory: []`.

In my code I manually push items in my array which save properly in the database, but whenever I wanna modify a field of one of my array object, it won't update it like a qty for example:

```js
player.inventory[i].qty += 1; //Where player is my model containing my inventory
...
player.save()
      .then((doc) => console.log("DOC", doc))
      .catch((err) => console.log("ERR", err));
```

and the doc returned look something like this:

```json
...
inventory: [
    {
      _id: 626a1468cdbeced19102942d,
      slug: 'crude_campfire',
      qty: 1,
      charges: 19,
      efficiency: -0.2
    },
    { _id: 626a14e7530afad2c5c1894c, slug: 'wheat', qty: 1 },
    { _id: 626a14f1530afad2c5c1894d, slug: 'carrot', qty: 1 },
    { _id: 626a150f530afad2c5c1894e, slug: 'potato', qty: 1 },
    { _id: 626a155b530afad2c5c1894f, slug: 'red_bream', qty: 1 },
    { _id: 626a15b5530afad2c5c18950, slug: 'bone', qty: 1 },
    { _id: 626a15c9530afad2c5c18951, slug: 'clam_shell', qty: 1 },
    { _id: 626a15d5530afad2c5c18952, slug: 'stone', qty: 8 },
    { _id: 626a15df530afad2c5c18953, slug: 'taeroot', qty: 1 },
    { _id: 626a15e9530afad2c5c18954, slug: 'shiny_pendant', qty: 1 },
    { _id: 626a15fd530afad2c5c18955, slug: 'sickleweed', qty: 1 },
    { _id: 626a1625530afad2c5c18956, slug: 'ceruleaf', qty: 1 },
    { _id: 626a1dba272403ea21fb71ef, slug: 'stone', qty: 1 },
    { _id: 626a1e4030a144f8179789e0, slug: 'birch_log', qty: 22 }, <- IMPORTANT
    { _id: 626a1e72372733f90cfdc003, slug: 'tree_twig', qty: 2 },
    { _id: 626a1e9a372733f90cfdc004, slug: 'honey', qty: 2 }
  ],
...
```

where you can see that my birch_log qty is now at 22. But whenever I go check in the database, [image: it is still at 8]

I don't know what's going on, and I'm kind of tired right, so I'll go to bed hoping someone can save me tomorrow :)

Thanks and have a good night ! :)

Answer (score 0):

To update the object having {slug: birch_log}, you can use the following query:

```
player.update( {user : 123456 , inventory.slug : "birch_log" } , 
               {$inc : {"inventory.$.qty" : 1} });
```

instead of using save() with promise, you can use update() query with async await. It will be short and clean code.

Comment: So what I do right now is I grab the player like this:
`const player = await PlayerModel.findOne({ user: data.userId });`
and then modify something in the player object and then player.save(). It used to work but now it doesn't anymore it's weird... I'll try your way and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah, now that I tried it doesn't really fit the way I'm doing it, since I'm first grabbing the player and then doing a bunch of things to it and then save it... The save returns the modified document, but in the db it didn't save… I can insert in the array, and it saves but not updating an array's field...

Answer (score 0):

[This answer fixed my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47123599/mongoose-instance-save-not-working-when-embedded-array-object-changed)

Since i'm using an "anonymous" array or whatever, mongoose doesn't know what changes to track in it so I need to tell it that it's been modified !